# Replace a string slice

Tags: javascript, string

This seems absurdly simple, but I'm having trouble thinking of a clean way to do this.

Consider:

```
var str = "foo bar foo bar foo bar";
```

I want to replace the second "foo bar" instance (i.e., `str.substring(8, 15)`) with an arbitrary string of arbitrary length.

Comment: Of course, in this case that's as trivial as concatenating a new string onto the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use

```
var str = "foo bar foo bar foo bar";
str = str.substring(0, 8) + "my new string" + str.substring(15)
```

You can even generalize with:

```
   var token = "foo bar";
   var newStr = "my new string";

   var str = "foo bar foo bar foo bar";
   str = str.substring(0, token.length+1) + 
           newStr + 
           str.substring(token.length*2+1);
```

Comment: One of those "oh, duh" moments for me - thanks so much. (will mark as answered as soon as SO lets me)

Comment: @Aaron: we all have those days :)

Answer (score 4):

I'd typically prefer to use the [Array.splice method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) for this sort of thing:

```
var str = "foo bar foo bar foo bar".split('');
str.splice(8, 7, 'newstring');
str = str.join('');
//"foo bar newstring foo bar"
```

If you're going to want to reuse this, then add it to strings:

```
if (!String.prototype.splice)
{
  String.prototype.splice = function(index, howmany, element){
    var arr = this.split('');
    arr.splice(index, howmany, element);
    return arr.join('');
  };
}
```

Of course this is a simple example that only handles a single inserted element. Splice for arrays handles multiple, but as such the strings would just be concatenated anyway, so one element is provided.

Using this method you could call:

```
a = "foo bar foo bar foo bar".splice( 8, 7, 'newstring' );
//a is now 'foo bar newstring foo bar'
```

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a prototype method for it:

```
String.prototype.sliceReplace = function(start, end, repl) {
    return this.substring(0, start) + repl + this.substring(end);
};

var s = "12345678";
s.sliceReplace(2,4, "-----"); // "12-----5678"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex:

```
"foo bar foo bar foo bar".replace(/foo bar (foo bar)/, '$1 testest'); // foo bar testtest foo bar
"notfoo notbar foo bar foo bar".replace(/foo bar (foo bar)/, '$1 testest'); // notfoo notbar foo bar testtest
```

or

```
var token = "foo bar";
var newStr = "new string";
var rg = new RegExp(token + ' (' + token + ')');
"foo bar foo bar foo bar".replace(rg, '$1 ' + newStr);
```